# I am having trouble positioning views in a full screen android app

Tags: android, android-layout

Hey thank you very much for that help and the code looks great but now I am just running into all sorts of problems... First I can not make a circle with the 2nd stacked ImageView, also I can not position the first 3 ImageViews to the top of the screen with 8dp of padding, it will literally not let me do anything without the whole thing becoming one big cluster. I have an image of what I am trying to achieve and will attach it. If you have any ideas all are welcome. Thank you very much by the way! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYOFq.png)

Comment: Yes, you can do that with the use of LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout for Top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

**XML code**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/fullscreenBackgroundColor"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Experiment.FullscreenContainer"
                tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">
            
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
            
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="8dp">
            
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />
            
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />
            
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    </LinearLayout>
            
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="200dp"
                            android:layout_margin="12dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            
                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                            android:layout_width="120dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cybersecurity_1134x638"
                            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            
                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                            android:text="Inner Button"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.762"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.795" />
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                        android:text="Button1"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
            
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                        android:text="Button2"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
            
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                        android:text="Button3"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
            
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                        android:text="Button4"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
            
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                        android:text="Button5"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
            
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
            
                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                            android:text="Button"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />
            
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_margin="12dp"
                            android:background="@color/black"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

**Design-Output**

[image]

Use https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView for Circle ImageView.

1. Add dependency in your app Level gradle file.

   implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
2. Add or replace ImageView to your XML file.

   ```
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cybersecurity_1134x638"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   ```

For Top Images I think you should check the height of the imageview Instead of wrap_content you can change with static value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have updated the post if you wanna take a peek so you can have a better understanding of what is going on now. You rock!